# couchdb import of letters like Ä, Ö, ü

Tags: import, export, couchdb, letters

Is there any opportunity to import a json file in couchdb with letters Like ä ü ö ?

I'm only using curl at a Windows machine.

After my import without ä ü ö. I Start futon and insert letters Like ä ü ö and it works. After i Export this document with these letters in a txt file it works also.

Import dies not work and Export work. What is the reason ?

Answer (score 1):

Check that you set HTTP "content-type" correctly to "application/json". JSON is UTF-8, so your Input has also be UTF-8.

Similar Question: [CouchDB and Special Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036553/couchdb-and-special-characters)

Comment: @Relaxo, did this answer work for you?  If yes, please accept the answer.  If not, you can write a comment here.